# Recorrer scrollview al final de forma automatica (xamarin forms)

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, microsoft

Quisiera saber si hay forma de modificar la posición de un **scrollview**, verán, resulta que tengo un **botón** que agrega contenido a un **stacklayout** dentro de un **scrollview**, pero llega un momento en que los elementos salen de la pantalla y el usuario tiene que arrastrar el **scrollview** para ir viendo cada nuevo elemento agregado, hay forma de hacer que siempre este viendo el final del **scrollview** de forma automática?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Allí se muestra que los elementos de taco y eso, siempre se muestran solo los primeros que agregue, el usuario tiene que arrastrar si o si siempre que quiera ver los otros que agrego, lo que quiero es que se vea el final del **scrollview** siempre.

Comment: Prueba a utilizar CollectionView. Tiene una propiedad que permite mantener el último elemento siempre visible, KeepLastItemInView